# AS400 Spring Boot Java Connection

Tags: spring-boot, db2, ibm-midrange

I am having following exeption trying to connect to db

`HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Receiver class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract setNetworkTimeout(Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;I)V of interface java.sql.Connection.)`

This is my pom

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
           <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
           <version>10.5</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

And application yaml

```
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:as400://xxx/xxx
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  driver-class-name: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
  hikari.connection-test-query: values 1
spring.jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
  hibernate.ddl-auto: none
```

Comment: You may get answers if you research https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues  (or ask a question there).

Comment: Did using <classifier>jt400_jdk6</classifier> in your dependency work?

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong version of jt400.jar. The default version is compiled with JDK 4.  The setNetworkTimeout method requires the Executor class which  wasn't added until JDK 1.6.  You'll need to use the version from java6/jt400.jar or java8/jt400.jar in the download package.

In Maven, you need to specify the jt400_jdk6 classifier.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
    <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
    <classifier>jt400_jdk6</classifier>
    <version>10.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, but getting following INFO log `com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-3 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (The driver does not support this function. (thread used != false))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jdk6-9 version (current for me now `'net.sf.jt400:jt400-jdk9:11.1'`)

Also you should use 'thread used=false' option like this:

```
jdbc:as400://${HOST};errors=full;thread used=false;keep alive=true;
```

More details in driver documentation
https://jt400.sourceforge.net/doc/com/ibm/as400/access/doc-files/JDBCProperties.html

> NOTE3: The socket timeout should only be used if the "thread used"
> property is set to false. By default, the JDBC driver will create a
> thread that is always blocked on a socket read waiting for a server
> response, and a connection idle longer than the socket timeout will
> drop the connection.

Comment: This worked for me as I was seeing that same log entry until I added the `thread used=false` to the DataSource properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated that `AS400JDBCConnectionImpl` and `AS400JDBCConnection` do not have `setNetworkTimeout(Executor executor, int milliseconds)` method. Maybe you can create a class from it and define the missing function. I couldn't test it, I hope it can be run.

Note: `package` location is important you should put in `com.ibm.as400.access` for accessing constructor of base class. Package can be located in your workspace like below picture.

[image: Sample layout]

```java
package com.ibm.as400.access;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class CustomAs400JDBCConnection extends AS400JDBCConnectionImpl {
    @Override
    public void setNetworkTimeout(Executor executor, int milliseconds) throws SQLException {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.setNetworkTimeout(milliseconds);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setClientInfo(Properties properties) {
        try {
            super.setClientInfo(properties);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setClientInfo(String s, String s1) {
        try {
            super.setClientInfo(s, s1);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

application.yaml

```yaml
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:as400://xxx/xxx
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  driver-class-name: com.ibm.as400.access.CustomAs400JDBCConnection
  hikari.connection-test-query: values 1
spring.jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
  hibernate.ddl-auto: none
```

Comment: there is no default constructor available in com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionImpl

Comment: did you put the new class under `com.ibm.as400.access` package. There was a problem with `setClientInfo` methods so I have updated the code.

Comment: hi thanks. getting error ```Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver```